# Pgfornaments Around Page Border

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfornament

I am attempting to create a simple certificate for a wedding ceremony using pgfornaments. I have never really been able to get my head around positioning nodes. I want the pattern to go around the border, like the poem example. Why is the line connecting CNE and CNW not working?[image] MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
\node[xshift = 3cm, yshift=-1cm, anchor=north] (CNW) at (current page.north west)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm]{61}};
 \node [xshift = -3cm, yshift=-1cm, anchor=north] (CNE)   at (current page.north east)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm, symmetry=v]{61}};
 \node[xshift = 3cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south] (CSW) at (current page.south west)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
 \node[xshift = -3cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south] (CSE)  at (current page.south east)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm, symmetry=c]{61}};

\pgfornamenthline{CNE}{CNW}{north}{87}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]  
\node[xshift = 3cm, yshift=-1cm, anchor=north] (CNW) at (current page.north west)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm]{61}};
 \node [xshift = -3cm, yshift=-1cm, anchor=north] (CNE)   at (current page.north east)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm, symmetry=v]{61}};
 \node[xshift = 3cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south] (CSW) at (current page.south west)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm,symmetry=h]{61}};
 \node[xshift = -3cm, yshift=1cm, anchor=south] (CSE)  at (current page.south east)
{\pgfornament[width=4cm, symmetry=c]{61}};

\path ([yshift=-5mm]CNW.north east) to [ornament=87] ([yshift=-5mm]CNE.north west);
\path[yscale=-1, transform shape] ([yshift=-5mm]CSW.south east) to [ornament=87] ([yshift=-5mm]CSE.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So i needed to incorporate the shift? Interesting. Hopefully that gets me closer.

Comment: @FrankZafka No, you don't need the shift. The shift was introduced because some part of central leaves were out the margin. The main change with your code is the use of `to [ornament...]` instead of `\pgfornamentline`.

Comment: I did get it sorted thanks to you. Hurts my brain really, but love the finished products. Thanks again.